Replacing a bounding box a shapefile in DEA Phenology code
I am using the DEA Sandbox Vegetation phenology notebook (https://knowledge.dea.ga.gov.au/notebooks/Real_world_examples/Vegetation_phenology/)
I am hoping to call on a shapefile rather than using lat/long as a bounding box with a buffer.
The code line is :
# Set the vegetation proxy to use
veg_proxy = 'NDVI'

# Define area of interest
lat = -33.3635
lon = 121.21
lon_buffer = 0.015
lat_buffer = 0.0075

# Set the range of dates for the analysis
time_range = ('2019-01-01', '2020-12-20')

I believe I need to import geopandas at the start,
and call on the shapefile path
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# Path to your shapefile
shapefile_path = 'path/to/your/shapefile.shp'

# Read the shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

# Extract the geometry of the first feature (assuming you have a single polygon)
geom = gdf.geometry.iloc[0]

# Get the bounding box (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
bounds = geom.bounds
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = bounds

# Convert the geometry to a GeoJSON-like dictionary
geom_json = mapping(geom)

# Set the range of dates for the analysis
time_range = ('2022-06-01', '2024-07-30')


So, what's your actual problem? Does the code run but fail to do what you anticipate? If so how does it fail to deliver? Does the code not run? (error message please) Does your computer spontaneously reboot? Catch fire? Run screaming down the hall?

Once you have your minx, miny, maxx, maxy (assuming your shapefile crs is geographic) you just use those values in the query as per cell [6] in the notebook you link to.
# Create a reusable query
query = {
    'y': [miny, maxy]  # lat_range,
    'x': [minx, maxx]  # lon_range,
    'time': time_range,
    'measurements': ['nbart_red', 'nbart_green', 'nbart_blue', 'nbart_nir_1'],
    'resolution': (-20, 20),
    'output_crs': 'epsg:6933',
    'group_by':'solar_day'
}

